# mysql_query inject - replace returned field

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

im trying to learn and understand mysql inject, i have created demo case.

```
SELECT ret_variable FROM data WHERE name = '".$name."' AND age = ".$age;
```

then `if(ret_variable == 2){something}` but query originally returns 1 and i need to force it to output 2

How to modify `$age` variable to set custom output field for `ret_variable`(only in response) ?
I have tried few ways with OR but didn't wroked.

Answer (score 0):

I see no practical application other than learning. I assume since you know the code , you have permission to test this out. So let's give it a go!

You can only return a 2 for the ret_variable when there is a row in the database with a value of 2 as the ret_variable and you know the name value of that row. You can for instance enter that name and the following to bypass the correct value for the age.

> age AND ret_value = 2

That would create the following query:

```
SELECT ret_variable FROM data WHERE name = 'John' AND age = age AND ret_value = 2;
```

The principle of mysql injection is this sort of manipulation of the query. But you can not force a value which is returned unless there is a row in the database with this value for ret_variable and you can somehow select this row.

When you don't know the name (or there is no record of your known name with a ret_variable of 2) it is not possible.

Since the AND operator has precedence over the OR operator you cannot manipulate the query to give a 2 as ret_variable. This is because the name = '?' part will always fail.